# I use sencha cmd Native Packaging for Android Tips: Unknown command: "package"

Tags: android, extjs

I refer to this article

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/native_packaging

I use sencha cmd Native Packaging for Android

Create a packaging configuration file

Tips: Unknown command: "package"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your query: `sencha package generate`

Did you mean: `sencha generate package`

Or: `sencha package build`

Comment: I refer to this article
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/native_packaging

Answer (score 0):

The correct command for version 5.0.2 is: `sencha generate package <packageName.json>`